# Implementing google dashboard type interface in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm looking at implementing a Google IG type dashboard in a .net app. There are a number of options I've found to do this, and i'm trying to establish what is going to be the best to use, in terms of speed, versatility etc.

So far the options I am looking at are either to use asp.net webparts and .net Ajax, this would make it quicker to build, but I'm concerned this is going to make the application bulky and slow, or using JQuery, and either .net MVC or Webforms, to custom build an interface.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what the best option may be, or any options I may have missed? All I want to do here is to allow users to customise a dashboard with a number of components (which will be user controls).

I do also have access to Telerik controls, but I'm not sure if they would be any use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik has a RadDock control that might come in handy, which works similar to the web parts feature (though some additional work is needed; it's not all built in, but it's not that much work).  Some of the other controls are really nice because they can bind via web services, which can help on performance (since WS calls happen after the page loads).

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar to this using this: [Dropthings](http://dropthings.omaralzabir.com/)

It worked out very well and is a much loved feature of our product.